# output semicolon separated values in field in databricks SQL

Tags: sql, databricks

Desired outcome:

```
+---------+-----------------------------+
| ID PR   | Related Repeating Event(s)  |
+---------+-----------------------------+
| 1658503 | 1615764;1639329             |
+---------+-----------------------------+
```

Is there a way to write a query in sql / databricks without using a User-defined aggregate functions (UDAFs)? I've tried concat(), GROUP_CONCAT(), LISTAGG but none of these work or are not supported in databricks ("This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.".

I found this User-defined aggregate functions (UDAFs) description in the databricks documentation but don't know how to implement it (https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html#user-defined-aggregate-functions-udafs&language-sql)

Would anybody have a hint for me or a link?

What I have is this basic query:

```
%sql
SELECT
  pr_id,
  data_field_nm,
  field_value
FROM
  gms_us_mart.txn_pr_addtl_data_detail_trkw_glbl --(18)
WHERE
 pr_id = 1658503
 AND data_field_nm = 'Related Repeating Deviation(s)'
```

Which gives as output:

```
+---------+--------------------------------+-------------+
| pr_id   | data_field_nm                  | field_value |
+---------+--------------------------------+-------------+
| 1658503 | Related Repeating Deviation(s) | 1615764     |
| 1658503 | Related Repeating Deviation(s) | 1639329     |
+---------+--------------------------------+-------------+
```

Correct answer is (thanks to @Alex Ott):

```
%sql
SELECT
 pr_id AS IDPR,
  concat_ws(';', collect_list(field_value)) AS RelatedRepeatingDeviations
FROM
  gms_us_mart.txn_pr_addtl_data_detail_trkw_glbl
WHERE
  data_field_nm = 'Related Repeating Deviation(s)'
  AND pr_id = 1658503
GROUP BY
  pr_id,
  data_field_nm;
```

Gives desired outcome:

```
+---------+-----------------------------+
| IDPR    | RelatedRepeatingDeviations  |
+---------+-----------------------------+
| 1658503 | 1615764;1639329             |
+---------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: not a udaf aspect

Comment: can u show code around it all pls,

Comment: added basic query for more context

Comment: so you have n rows and want to make an rev from them. pls show input and expected output

Comment: I've updated the question with all info I have, see query and its output.

Comment: thx for that, not sure possible with %sql

Comment: No, the '%sql' magic command isn't actually needed at all, tried both ways, no difference

Comment: good for you...

Comment: Oracle listagg() allows an order by clause. collect_list() does not. Is there any way to accomplish that in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `group by` with `collect_list` and `concat_ws`, like this:

- get data

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(**{'pr_id':1658503, 'data_field_nm':'related', 'field_value':1615764}), 
                            Row(**{'pr_id':1658503, 'data_field_nm':'related', 'field_value':1639329})])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("abc")
```

- and do the query:

```sql
%sql

select pr_id, 
  data_field_nm, 
  concat_ws(';', collect_list(field_value)) as combined 
from abc 
group by pr_id, data_field_nm
```

although this will give you the column with the fixed name (`combined`)

Comment: thanks @alex, I've updated/edited my question with the adapted answer and got the desired outcome.

Comment: yes, bad manuals for a noob like me. All you get as info on the databricks doc site: "collect_list(expr) - Collects and returns a list of non-unique elements." A tiny example would have helped me a lot and saved hours of searching and trying

Comment: Yeah, that’s a problem - sql docs are mostly coming from Spark docs themselves. In these cases, sites like https://sparkbyexamples.com/ could be helpful

Comment: thanks for the spark site  - that's exactly what I was looking for :)